# PDAL +init use deprecated but what is the alternative

Tags: proj, syntax, pdal

With PDAL I was trying to using a proj4 string like `+init=epsg:32615 +geoidgrids=C:\vdatum_GEOID12A\vdatum\core\geoid12a\g2012au7.gtx` based on an example given on the PDAL website https://pdal.io/en/stable/stages/filters.reprojection.html#example-2

When running the command with this Proj4 string I get the warning

> Warning 1: +init=epsg:XXXX syntax is deprecated. It might return a CRS with a non-EPSG compliant axis order.

but I can't find an alternative to the syntax given in the example.

Comment: Maybe the Proj string that does not read the parameters from the CSV file like `+init` does is more explicit. You can get the string with projinfo: `projinfo epsg:32615
PROJ.4 string:
+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs`. The WKT2 string that projinfo also prints should be fully specified and thus the best option, though not handy to write by hand.

Answer (score 0):

As I've been looking for the same answer, maybe someone else ends up in this thread and can use this. The easiest alternative is st_crs(NUMBER), for example st_crs(4326). Both `sf`.

So for me it went from

```
crs_inuse <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
```

to

```
crs_inuse <- st_crs(4326)
```

Derived from this explanation: https://inbo.github.io/tutorials/tutorials/spatial_crs_coding/